# Session token (next-auth.session-token) disappears quickly after login when using NextAuth with Azure AD

Tags: azure, next.js, next-auth

I'm encountering an issue with session token management in my Next.js application using NextAuth with Azure AD authentication. After a user logs in, the `next-auth.session-token` session token seems to disappear very quickly, requiring the user to log in again even when refreshing the page.

Here is my next auth configuration:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const fetchProxyAddresses = async (accessToken: any) => {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

  const response = await fetch(
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=displayName,proxyAddresses",
    { headers },
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Graph API call failed: ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  console.log(response.json);

  return response.json();
};

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID || "defaultClientId",
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET || "defaultClientSecret",
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID || "defaultTenantId",
      authorization: { params: { scope: "openid profile User.Read email" } },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // Persist the access_token to the token right after sign in
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      const maxAge = 24 * 60 * 60;

      // Fetch proxyAddresses if access token is available
      if (account?.access_token) {
        try {
          const userData = await fetchProxyAddresses(account.access_token);
          token.proxyAddresses = userData.proxyAddresses;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to fetch user proxyAddresses:", error);
        }
      }

      return {
        ...token,
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + maxAge,
      };
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Pass the accessToken and proxyAddresses to the session
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.proxyAddresses = token.proxyAddresses;

      return session;
    },
  },
});
```